# Audi 2012 S5 starter problem

Tags: audi, s5

Reading some articles here, it sounds like my Audi PGM fi relay is faulty, car has intermittent starting problem.
after driving for a while and leaving the car for an hour or so when I get back engine cranks but no start, come back in 30 minutes then she starts.
Where is the PGM fi Relay situated in the car, is it under dash?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Looks like PGM-FI is a Honda/Acura name for Programmed Fuel Injection.  Do you think the fuel pump is not coming on or something else?